# Help with rendering "wispy stocking effect" / emission shader / texture / material

Tags: rendering, animation-nodes

I'm trying to reproduce the image below in Blender 2.8 [image]
From the a Strange Attractor [site](https://denisegaskins.com/2014/01/30/alexandria-jones-and-the-strange-attractor/)

I've tried using an emission shader and converting points to a curve but it doesn't even come close.

[image: Node network]

[image: Emission node]

My current render try is below along with the attached blend file.  It's as though I can't get the lines thin enough.
[image]

Any ideas of how to fix it?  My ultimate goal is to animate various strange attractors while changing their
values.

I can animate the equation thanks to the help of numerous people in the Blender community.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a setup with volumetrics?

Comment: @Corbomite no I haven't, Thanks I'll read more about it next.

Comment: I could be being stupid here but- scale everything apart from the spline radius by 10?...

Comment: @MarkS no it's not stupid I find that every idea helps me out.  I could have over looked something because Blender can do so much my view may be to narrow. That does help but doesn't give it that "sharp whispy stocking effect" since the lines are the same width.

Comment: This might sound odd then: but I remember the scene from '300' with all the whispy smokey shit around the 'oracle' chick, and remember seeing it was done with Lightwave cloth- https://www.awn.com/vfxworld/300-its-miller-time-cg I even found an article! It might be worth a thought...

Comment: Not an answer since it's not controlled with an equation but still interesting...
https://youtu.be/rtPzXrZ23k0?t=168